# Extending from JsonMediaTypeFormatter to set customer headers doesn't work with http Accept header

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, mediatypeformatter

My goal is to add certain custom headers to every outgoing JSON response. To do this, created a class that extends from SetDefaultContentHeaders JsonMediaTypeFormatter, and overrode the SetDefaultContentHeaders method like so:

```
public override void SetDefaultContentHeaders(Type type, HttpContentHeaders headers, MediaTypeHeaderValue mediaType)
{
    base.SetDefaultContentHeaders(type, headers, mediaType);
    headers.Add("X-Answer", "42");
    headers.Add("X-Question", "Unknown");
}
```

I then prepended my derived media type formatter to the formatters list:

```
config.Formatters.Insert(0, new MyMediaTypeFormatter());
```

And this solution seems to work for some requests, but not others. After some investigation, I discovered that if I include an 'Accept' header in the request, the response does not contain my custom headers! This was a bit surprising, because the response type still comes back application/json, suggesting either my formatter or the default json formatter is handling the response. The only thing I can think is that the code that calls `SetDefaultContentHeaders` is *in* the `JsonMediaTypeFormatter`, and that `SetDefaultContentHeaders` is not virtual.

So - what is going on here? And what is the best way(s) to correct this?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, media type formatters are concerned with encoding related headers only. If you want to add custom headers, you should use [`DelegatingHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) or [`ActionFilter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.actionfilterattribute%28v=vs.118%29.aspx). You can apply both globally (inserting them in the appropriate collection in the configuration class) and per-action for the later. An example, using `DelegatingHandler` would look like:

```
public class JsonHeaderHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
        HttpRequestMessage message, CancellationToken token)
    {
        var response = await base.SendAsync(message, token);
        IEnumerable<string> contentTypes;

        if(response.Headers.TryGetValues("Content-Type", out contentTypes)) 
        {
            // Check if there is an application/json Content-Type header
            // There should be 0 or 1, a call to FirstOrDefault() would be fine
            if(contentTypes.Any(ct => ct.Contains("application/json")))
            {
                response.Headers.Add("X-Answer", "42");
                response.Headers.Add("X-Question", "Unknown");
            }
        }

        return response;
    }
}

// And using HttpConfiguration configuration
configuration.MessageHandlers.Add(new JsonHeaderHandler());
```

Comment: Will definitely give this a shot! I am still rather curious *why* my given implementation stops working with an accept header, but having a solution to the symptom is definitely a good step forward.

Comment: @Rollie I've had issue with custom headers within media type formatters. I haven't invested time into finding out the why as there is an alternative in the pipeline.